# Finding a parametrization of the solutions of $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{\sinh y}{\cosh y+A\cos x}$, $\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{A\sin x}{\cosh y+A\cos x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, chaos-theory

I am trying desperately to find a parametrization for the following:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{\sinh y}{\cosh y+A\cos x}$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{A\sin x}{\cosh y+A\cos x}$

I tried to devide the equation and do several manipulation - no actual success. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't understand: parametrizations are usually for surfaces, paths or something like that. You have here two differentials of, apparently, two functions $\;x,\,y\;$ of $\;t\;$ ...yet $\;t\;$ doesn't appear on the right side. What do you **exactly** want? What is the background? What is *all* the information given. Finally, if still you want to parametrize something, tell us *what*.

Comment: Eventually, I want to find the Melnikov function for this system (+ a perturbation). The first step is to find the unperturbed trajectory. This is why I need to find $x(t)$ and $y(t)$. I succeeded in former exercises, but not in this one.

Comment: Maybe it helps to notice that the system is Hamiltonian: $dx/dt=\partial H/\partial y$, $dy/dt=-\partial H/\partial x$, where $H(x,y) = \ln|\cosh y + A \cos x|$. So $H$ is a constant of motion.

Comment: @Joanpemo: What is sought is simply an explicit formula for the solution $(x(t),y(t))$ (where $t$ is the "parameter").

Comment: You could divide the two equations. Using the chain rule, you get $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{sinh y }{Acos x }$ which is a seperable ODE, integrate then parametrize it as you please.

Comment: @Asemismaiel - you should post that as an answer. It is the path to the solution.

Comment: Note that $$A(\sin x)x'=\frac{A\sin x\sinh y}{\cosh y+A\cos x}=(\sinh y)y'$$ hence $$(\cosh y+A\cos x)'=0$$ and, for every $t$, $$\cosh y(t)+A\cos x(t)=\cosh y(0)+A\cos x(0).$$